# Let $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ given by $ T(z)=(1+i)z$. Represent the set $R=\{x+iy\in \mathbb{C}:x=y \}$ and find the set $T(R)$

Tags: complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ given by $ T(z)=(1+i)z$. Represent the set $R=\{x+iy\in \mathbb{C}:x=y \}$ and find the set $T(R)$

---

The representation of  $R$ is the straight line $y=x$ in the Cartesian Plane.

The set $T(R)=(1+i)(y+yi)=(y+yi+yi-y)=2yi=\{x+2iy\in \mathbb{C}:x=0 \}$

---

**Is correct my answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but you could do like this:

$$ T(1+i) = (1+i)^2y = 2iy$$

You could also add that $y$ is arbitrary: $T(R)=\{x+2iy\in \mathbb{C}:x=0,y\in\mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: thanks, can you help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483446/find-the-image-through-t-of-the-square-with-vertices-1-1-i-i