# Find the image through $T$ of the square with vertices $1,-1,i,-i$

Tags: complex-numbers, geometric-transformation

$T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ given by $ T(z)=(1+i)z$.

---

$ T(1)=1+i $

$T(-1)=-1-i$

$T(i)=-1+i$

$T(-i)=1-i$

So the image is the square with vertices$ T(1),T(-1),T(i)$ and $(T-i)$ ?

Comment: You have shown where the corners are sent. It remains to show that the edges are actually sent to straight lines so that you get a square, and not, say, a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $T$ is linear it is similarity transformation (preserves the angles and ratio of distances) with factor of similarity $\sqrt{2}$:

$$|T(z)-T(w)| = |(1+i)(z-w)|= |1+i||z-w| = \sqrt{2}|z-w|$$

so it takes square to square which is bigger than first one with factor $\sqrt{2}$.